# [Paraview]- Compare two Vtk mesh surface to calculate the deformation distance

Tags: distance, intersection, mesh, surface, paraview

I have a tof camera (pmd camboard nano), and my goal it's to between meshes calculate the distance from each other to calculate the deformation distance and the 3d position of specific points.
What is the best method to make that? I try with ruler, and euclidian distance in matlab with the point source, but i want the calcultion to be more precise.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution, assuming both datasets have exactly the same number of points and you are comparing point coordinates for points at the same index:

1. Apply the `Calculator` filter on both the datasets separately with the expression `coords`. This will create new datasets with  *Result* array in the PointData that corresponds to the point locations for each of the datasets.
2. Select the two calculator filters and then apply the `Python Calculator` filter with *expression* set to `sqrt(sum((inputs[0].PointData["Result"] - inputs[1].PointData["Result"])**2))`.

The resulting dataset will have a *result* array which is the euclidean distance between the two corresponding points.

To limit this calculation to specific points, you can use the `Extract Selection` or `Threshold` to extract smaller datasets with points of interest and then do the above.